# How to find the X-intercept of a slope in Java?

Tags: java, math

I've never used Java, one of my programming friends gave me this to try and get used to Java.

He gave me the test.java file along with some pointers for making the line class. However, I still don't know how to write code for the slope or y_int. I assume for vert I continue to use a Boolean and if/else statement but I am a bit lost.

this is the Test.java:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args ) {

        Line line[] = {new Line(5,4),
            new Line(0,2),
            new Line(5)};

        int i = 1;
        for(Line li : line){
            System.out.println("The x-intercept of line "+i+" is "+
                li.getX_int());
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

this is the Line.java Class:

```
public class Line {

    public double slope;
    public double y_int;
    public double x_int;
    public boolean vert;

    public Line(double slope, double y_int){
        this.slope = slope;
        this.y_int = y_int;
        vert = false;
    }   

    public Line(double x_int) {
        slope = Double.NaN;
        y_int = Double.NaN;
        vert = true;
        this.x_int = x_int;
    }

    public double getSlope() {
        return slope;
    }

    public double getY_int() {
        return y_int;
    }

    public boolean isVert() {
        return vert;
    }
}
```

Comment: HINT: for non-vertical lines, x_intercept = (0 - y_intercept) / slope

Answer (score 2):

Think about root definitions for things.

Your equation for a line is:

```
y(x) = m*x + b
```

where

```
m = slope
b = y-intercept
```

You calculate the x-intercept by setting y equal to zero and solving for x:

```
x-intercept = -b/m
```

This will let you down for `m = 0`, because you can't divide by zero.  In that case there *is* no x-intercept.  That's a line parallel to the x-axis.

Likewise there *is* no y-intercept for a vertical line parallel to the y-axis.

What do you plan to set for intercepts for those extreme cases?